# What can cause Play automatic recompilation to break?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808053/java-play-2-does-not-recompile)

Somehow something I did cause Play to stop recompiling my sources.
I killed the process, did `play clean` and `play start` again.

I verified there isn't another rouge play process.

I believe that what triggered the problem was me trying to debug it using `play debug`. Is there anything I can do to find out why my recompilation is broken?

Comment: You have to use `play run` for automatic recompilation, not `play start`

Comment: @nico_ekito - are you sure? Is this documented anywhere?  I tried and it doesn't work, even though the console prints ` auto-reloading is enabled`

Comment: Check my answer on the other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15076154/320180

Comment: @nico_ekito - thanks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075996/what-can-cause-play-automatic-recompilation-to-break/15076577#15076577

Comment: hey, you stole my answer ;-)

Comment: @nico_ekito - with reference :) If you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075843/what-is-the-equivalent-to-play-stop-for-play-framework-2-1/15076154#15076154), `play run` has recompilation, `play start` is for production mode. In my case, I had a rouge process that was started with play start.

To resolve:

1. Kill all suspect java.exe processes
2. `play clean`
3. `play run`